# std::function accepting different function signatures in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, events, std-function, stdbind

I'm trying to create a c++ event system similar to c# system.
I need to be able to store any kind of functions and call them with the right parameters at the appropriate time.

The closest I can get is with std::function, bind and placeholders but here is my problem.

```
void Func()
{
    std::cout << "Notified" << std::endl;
}

void FuncWithParam(const std::string& str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

std::function<void()> fn = std::bind(Func); // this works

std::function<void()> fn = std::bind(FuncWithParam, "Hello there"); // this works also

std::function<void()> fn = std::bind(FuncWithParam, _1); // but this doesn't
```

Is it actually possible to store any kind of signature in a single std::function ? Or do I have to recourse to a more complex solution.

Comment: Not any kind, no. You specify a signature right there in the template argument. Convertibility makes the types negotiable, but the number of function parameters is fixed.

Comment: It's possible to build such a thing, but the question remains that when you can put any callable in there, how do you know that you're calling it properly? Perhaps you're looking for something like a [type-safe heterogeneous event system](https://github.com/ldionne/cppnow-2017-fun-with-boost-hana/blob/gh-pages/code/callbacks.hana.hetero.cpp).

Comment: I was hoping not to use Boost but your answer actually put a name on what I was trying to do. That should keep me going

Comment: FWIW, Hana existed independently before being part of Boost. It's entirely possible to use it without Boost.

Comment: Oh that's not just about Boost. I'd like to be able to solve this without using any external dependencies. But I'll definitely try Hana or even Boost::Signal if I need to.

Comment: If you can live with the reduced type safety, you could always just resort to `std::vector<std::any> const& params`.

Comment: I am uncertain what parts of C# events you want to mimic and why.  Are you talkimg about the optimized storage where many kinds of events are stored together, which exists because C# library UI controls exposes many mire events than most any sane consumer would listen to?  If so, are you writing a framework for many thousands of consumers, and publishing unused events by 99% if users makes sense?  Or some other feature/reaaon?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Can you develop ? I'm not sure where you want to go but I didn't know about std::any and it does sound interesting

Comment: @Yakk I want to be able to subscribe and unsubscribe to events that I can later call with the params I want. I implemented this [link](https://cratonica.wordpress.com/implementing-c-events-in-c/) but it doesn't support callbacks with different parameter types. I can use a common abstract class to solve the problem but it sounds very wrong

Comment: @LRP: `std::any` became available in C++17, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any and the examples at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast

Comment: @LRP That was amazingly vague.  And the linked code looks like Java/C# code, not C++ code.  Why not start with `std::function`, and it seems to have nothing to do with storing "any kind of signature".  I have no idea *why* you want to store "any kind of signature"; you want the kinds of signatures *invoked* to match the kinds of signatures *registered*, and you want that checked at compile time, if you are sane.

Comment: @Yakk Sorry for the vague answer. Linked code is definitely C++ as I use std::function and std::bind. Anyway variadic templates is what I was looking for. See accepted answer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl std::any looks like a game changer for a lot of situations. I will definitely spend some time learning c++17. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple C++ broadcaster:

```
using token = std::shared_ptr<void>;

template<class...Ts>
struct broadcaster {
  using listen = std::function<void(Ts...)>;
  using sp_listen = std::shared_ptr<listen>;
  using wp_listen = std::weak_ptr<listen>;

  token attach( listen l ) {
    return attach( std::make_shared<listen>(std::move(l)) );
  }
  token attach( sp_listen sp ) {
    listeners.push_back(sp);
    return sp;
  }
  void operator()(Ts...ts)const {
    listeners.erase(
      std::remove_if( begin(listeners), end(listeners),
        [](auto&& wp){return !(bool)wp.lock();}
      ),
      end(listeners)
    );
    auto tmp = listeners;
    for (auto&& l : tmp) {
      if (auto pf = l.lock()) {
        (*pf)(ts...);
      }
    }
  }
private:
  mutable std::vector<wp_listen> listeners;
};
```

To listen to it, you `.attach` and pass it a function to call.  `attach` returns a `token`, and the function is invoked so long as that token (or copies of it) continue to exist.

To invoke the message, you invoke `()` on the `broadcaster`.

Memory of dead callbacks is reclaimed the next time you invoke the broadcaster; indirectly owned resources are cleaned up faster.

If you register a listener while it is currently broadcasting, it won't get the current broadcast.

You can add a `std::mutex` to make this usable from multiple threads at once, or externally synchronize.  If you synchronize internally, I wouldn't hold the mutex as you run the `for(auto&&` loop in `()` to avoid reentrancy problems.

Example use:

```
struct location {
  int x, y;
};
struct button {
  broadcaster< location > mouse_click;
  broadcaster<> mouse_enter;
  broadcaster<> mouse_leave;
};

struct dancer {
  std::vector<token> listen_tokens;
  dancer( button& b ) {
    listen_tokens.push_back( b.mouse_enter.attach([this]{ dance(); } ) );
    listen_tokens.push_back( b.mouse_leave.attach([this]{ end_dance(); } ) );
    listen_tokens.push_back( b.mouse_click.attach(
      [this](location l){
        pose(l.x, l.y);
      }
    ) );
  }
  void dance() const {
    std::cout << "start dancing\n";
  }
  void pose( int x, int y ) const {
    std::cout << "struck a pose at " << x << ", " << y << "\n";
  }
  void end_dance() const {
    std::cout << "end dancing\n";
  }
};
```

Note that no `virtual` methods where used.  The only polymorphism was type erasure based on `std::function`.

Listening objects have to track the lifetime they which to listen over explicitly (by keeping a `token` alive), and if they want to be able to unregister to a specific broadcaster they have to keep that association themselves.

If broadcasters go away first, there is no problem.  If listeners go away, so long as their token preceeds them everything is ok.  Attaching does cause a dynamic allocation to store the token (and a moved into copy of the listener), but only one.

This is a different approach than you'd use in C#, both because it relies on RAII and because it is not OO at its core, yet remains polymorphic.

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for. I had difficulties making it work with variadic templates. The mutex is a nice touch also. I'll keep you updated if I run into some difficulties implementing it. Thanks.